# Excel formula to enhance depreciation pro-rated formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am building a file to calculate the depreciation amount of several items with various capitalization dates and depreciation rates. I currently have worked something out but it seems too basic, I am trying to fit as many of the already created formulas from column I to N into one to make it nice and clean. I am struggling to mix & match formuals to get there. Any suggestions on which formuals I should use is most welcomed.

From column A to G, it is data generated by a system. From Column I to N is the couple of basic formulas I have added.

Cell I13 has: `=YEAR($C$10)-YEAR(B13)`
Cell J13 has: `=MONTH($C$10)-MONTH(B13)+1`
Cell K13 has: `=(I13*12)+J13`
Cell L13 has: `=VLOOKUP(A13,$B$4:$D$8,3,FALSE)`
Cell M13 has: `=VLOOKUP(A13,$B$4:$E$8,4,FALSE)`
Cell N13 has: `=IF(K13<M13,-C13*K13/M13,-C13)`

The depreciation is calculated from the month of purchase of the asset (capitalisation date) and not by day.

[image]

Comment: On the 10 questions you asked, only 4 are marked as answered. No good replies or bad behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I to N on one formula

```
=-MIN($C13,$C13/VLOOKUP($A13,$B$4:$E$8,4,0)*(DATEDIF($B13,$C$10,"M")+1))
```

Comment: That works, I just changed all the ";" with ","

Answer (score 1):

You could make your life easier using Excel 'hidden' `DATEDIF()` function.
`=DATEDIF(startDate, endDate, "M")` will return the difference in months.
There is a good explanation  about it [here](https://www.ptr.co.uk/blog/using-datedif-function-microsoft-excel) and from Microsoft [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38).
You will have to type it manually, strangely it is not available in the list of functions.